# How do I write a basic test class for my pageBlockTable controller?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am very new to Apex code development, and am stumped on how to create a test class for my basic controller.  Here is my controller:

```
public class BuyerAlert{

    public List<Buyer__c> listOfBuyer {get; set;}
    public Buyer__c Buyer {get;set;}

    public BuyerAlert() {
        listOfBuyer = [Select id, name, Raw_Conversion__c, Call_Dur__c, Sold_Calls_Today__c from Buyer__c WHERE  Buyer_Call_Handling_Alert__c = TRUE ORDER BY Sold_Calls_Today__c DESC];
    }
}
```

I have searched everywhere, and tried using a dozen different templates but keep hitting a wall.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a separate test class (i.e. BuyerAlertTest.cls)
2. Add the following annotation at the top of the class: @isTest. 
   Aside: You can also use @seeAllData=True, but this is not advisable. There is a myriad of articles online discussing this topic which is out of the scope of this question.
3. Create a test method
4. Create sample data for your object. We recommend creating a Test Utility class that can contain your sample test data, but for now, let's just focus on a simple test class.

   ```
    @isTest
    public class BuyerAlertTest
    {
       public static testmethod void testBuyerAlertConstructor()
       {
            try
            {
              // Create sample data.
              Buyer__c buyer = new Buyer__c ();
              buyer.Name = 'Test Buyer';
              buyer.Sold_Calls_Today__c = 5;
              upsert buyer;

              // Instantiate your controller class now
              BuyerAlert buyerAlert = new BuyerAlert();

              // Verify your data with relevant predicates. You only have a constructor to test, so this is just a basic assertion
              system.assertEquals('Test Buyer', buyer.Name);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               system.debug(ex.getMessage());
            }
       } 
   }
   ```